# Retrieve all jars from Local jfrog Repository using Maven

Tags: maven, jar, artifactory

I am hosting a Local Repository with 80+ Jar files which are related to our internal Project

Something like this
[image]

I want to add a tag in my Maven pom.xml where in I retrieve all the jar files in one shot when I create a new project in Eclipse.

These jars are static and will not change.

Can anyone please help in setting up this?

In Artifactory - **"Set me Up"**, I can see this TAG, but its for pushing a final jar

[image]

Comment: I understand this: when a new Maven project is created via Eclipse, there have to be certain dependency entries in the new projects `pom.xml`?

Comment: Here is my case, all the 80+ jar files are needed for the project, I want to retrieve everything without explicitly mentioning each jar in dependency tag

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two options:

#### 1. Use a parent pom

Add all the 80 dependencies to a POM which looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>ourDependencies</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging> <!-- IMPORTANT -->

    <dependencies>
         <!-- place here 80 dependencies -->
         <dependency>
         ...
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>   <!-- optional -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
    ...                             <!-- optional -->
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

In the project that needs the dependencies, add a `<parent>` element to the `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project>
    <groupId>your.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>newApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>  <!-- or war or ... -->
    ....
    <parent>
        <groupId>your.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>ourDependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>
    ...
</project>
```

**Keep in mind that every project can have only one parent.**

#### 2. Create an archetype

This way is more complex. You can create a simple project similar to "HelloWorld" which contains all the dependencies. Based on this project, you can create an archetype which serves as a template when you create a new Maven project.
More Informations:
[Introduction to archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html)
[archetype tutorial](http://geekofficedog.blogspot.de/2013/08/creating-maven-archetypes-tutorial.html)